# Array of parametrs to MD5 key

Tags: php, md5

I have Script in php:

```
<?php   
$secretkey='1kaSutSkaDstekSko345QQeVa3ratko1aAKSU2stIHFH44fheo1FhHEfo2oe6fifhkhs'; 
$parray = array($tagId, $userId);
$validate = serialize($parray);
$key=md5($validate.$secretkey); 
?>
<a href="delfollow.php?tagid=<?php echo $tagId ?>&userid=<?php echo $userId ?>&key=<?php echo $key ?>">Delete</a>
```

And in delfollow.php:

```
$userId = $_GET['userid'];
$tagId = $_GET['tagid'];
$key = $_GET['key'];

$secretkey='1kaSutSkaDstekSko345QQeVa3ratko1aAKSU2stIHFH44fheo1FhHEfo2oe6fifhkhs'; 
$parray = array($tagId, $userId);
$validate = serialize($parray);
$nkey=md5($validate.$secretkey); 

echo $key."<br/>";
echo $nkey."<br/>";
```

And this keys are diferent! why.

Comment: $_GET parameters are passed as strings by default so serialize would return a different string.

Comment: And how I can fix this problem?

Comment: cast the values to int:
`$parray = array((int) $tagId, (int) $userId);`

Answer (score 0):

you can **echo $validate.$secretkey;** before both of two md5() and then compare the difference between two string.

Comment: Yes serialized arrays are different:
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"169";i:1;i:6;}
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"169";i:1;s:1:"6";}
But why?

Comment: @user2783755 as cecilozaur said , php treats $_GET parameters as string, and you set $userid as number in the first code